# select all row except those specified in the subquery

Tags: mysql

I make a selection on request and it behaves correctly.

```
SELECT t1.id, MIN(t1.rate) 
FROM offers AS t1 
WHERE t1.stock > 0 
GROUP BY t1.ean;
```

AS soon as I nest it in another query, then the difficulty arises that WHERE NOT IN expects one column, but I need to keep MIN for GROUP BY to be preserved.

Here is query:

```
SELECT t2.id, t2.name, t2.ean 
FROM offers AS t2 
WHERE t2.id NOT IN (SELECT t1.id, MIN(t1.rate) 
                    FROM offers AS t1 
                    WHERE t1.stock > 0 
                    GROUP BY t1.ean);
```

Comment: what is the result for the second request ??? there is the use of MIN function, in the subquery you will have at least one line

Comment: The results fot the second query will be 'unknown' (or version specific), because you are selecting a different field than is uses in the group by. In standard SQL it is an invalid query because a guess has to be made which id to return based on the group.  (more info: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by )

Comment: I need all Id from subQuery request to exclude them from the total selection. Like give me all items except this rows.

Comment: Then select only `id` in you sub query? and not a  `MIN(rate)` because you are doing nothing with that value .

Comment: but it seems to help me select the row with the minimum value in the groups. Or was I wrong here too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is answer:

```
SELECT t1.id 
FROM offers AS t1 
WHERE  t1.id NOT IN (
    SELECT f.id
    FROM (SELECT 
            ean,
            Min(net_price) AS minprice,
            stock
          FROM offers
          GROUP  BY ean
         ) 
    AS x INNER JOIN offers 
     AS f ON f.ean = x.ean AND f.net_price = x.minprice);
```